# How to send multiple objects from Angular2 to Java Spring backend

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, angular

I am trying to send two objects (`CustomerAcct` and `Product`) from Angular 2 to restful services (Java Spring). I am using a wrapper object called `CustProduct`, which has two objects in it, `CustomerAcct` and Product. Somehow on the back end `CustomerAcct` object is null but Product object is not.

Here is my code:

GUI:

CustProduct class:

```
export class CustProduct { public ca: CustomerAcct; public prod: Product }
```

Service:

```
addProductToCustomer(cp: CustProduct): Observable<Boolean> {

     let body = JSON.stringify(cp);
     let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     let url = 'my-url';

     return this.http.post(my-url, body, options)
                     .map(this.extractData)
                     .catch(this.hadnleError);
}
```

Backend code:

```
java classes:
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER_ACCT")
public class CustomerAcct {
    @Id
@Column(name="CUSTOMER_ACCT_ID")
private long CUSTOMER_ACCT_ID;
@Column (name="CUSTOMER_NAME")
private long CUSTOMER_NAME;

other additional fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {
@Id
@Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
private long PRODUCT_ID;
@Column(name="PROD_DESC")
private String PROD_DESC;

other additional fields
  }

public class CustomerProduct {
CustomerAcct customerAcct;
Product product;
}

public boolean addProductToCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerProduct cp) {
       CustomerAcct ca = cp.customerAcct;
       Product prod = cp.product;

       // Here CustomerAcct is null, but I do see data in Product object
}
```

I don't understand why it is dropping `CustomerAcct` object. If I send `CustomerAcct` object in `@RequestBody` by itself, it works but not in the wrapper object. My class definitions on GUI and backend are same.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Java class definitions?

Comment: @chrylis        Entity
Table(name="CUSTOMER_ACCT")
public class CustomerAcct {
    id
   Column(name="CUSTOMER_ACCT_ID")
 private long CUSTOMER_ACCT_ID;
   Column (name="CUSTOMER_NAME")
 private long CUSTOMER_NAME;
}

Entity  Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {
 Id
 Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
 private long PRODUCT_ID;
 Column(name="PROD_DESC")
 private String PROD_DESC;
}

public class CustomerProduct {
 CustomerAcct customerAcct;
 Product product;
}

Comment: I am using '@'Column, '@'Id @Table annotations in the class, but the here it is not allowing me to add '@' sign here. Hope you get my point. Thanks

Comment: Edit them into your question, and it should work fine.

Comment: @chrylis  Thanks for putting up with me. I am new to this site. I just edited in my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a simple JSON conversion, which means that in the JSON object your keys are `ca` and `prod`. By default, Jackson expects the keys to match the field names, which are `customerAcct` and `product`. The simplest approach is probably to annotate your Java fields with `@JsonField("ca")`. (Alternately, you could rename the properties in either Java or JavaScript.)

Comment: @Jpatel If you find an answer helpful, you can upvote it with the arrow next to it. If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it by selecting the check mark under the arrows.